# Creating threads recursively in java

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I have this code that creates threads recursively and I can't seem to figure out how it stops the threads from running.

```
public class Recursive_Thread {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numThreads = 10;

    /* create and start thread 0 */

    System.out.println("Starting thread 0");
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Inner(0, numThreads));
    thread.start();        

    /* wait for thread 0 */

    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

    System.out.println("Threads all done");
}
/* inner class containing code for each thread to execute */

private static class Inner extends Thread {

    private int myID;
    private int limit;

    public Inner(int myID, int limit) {
        this.myID = myID;
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello World from " + myID);

        /* do recursion until limit is reached */
        if (myID == limit) {
              System.out.println("Good Bye World from " + myID);
        } else {
              System.out.println("Starting thread " + (myID+1));
              Thread thread = new Thread(new Inner((myID+1), limit));
              thread.start();
              try {
                  thread.join();
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {System.out.println("Well... That didn't go as planned!");}
              System.out.println("Thread " + (myID+1) + " finished");
              System.out.println("Good Bye World from " + myID);
        }
    }

}
```

I ran the debugger and the execution seems to stop after going through this line after the message for the 10th thread has been printed

```
System.out.println("Good Bye World from " + myID);
```

and somehow the execution goes back to these lines

```
System.out.println("Thread " + (myID+1) + " finished");
System.out.println("Good Bye World from " + myID);
```

for every remaining thread after the 10th one. How do I get from

```
if (myID == limit) {
              System.out.println("Good Bye World from " + myID);
```

to

```
else {
              System.out.println("Starting thread " + (myID+1));
              Thread thread = new Thread(new Inner((myID+1), limit));
              thread.start();
              try {
                  thread.join();
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {System.out.println("Well... That didn't go as planned!");}
              System.out.println("Thread " + (myID+1) + " finished");
              System.out.println("Good Bye World from " + myID);
        }
```

Does the join method create some kind of checkpoint for the program to go back to after finishing with the creation of all 10 threads?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Same for me, i tried running your program and the output is exactly what i would expect. Is your question, why you get the `Good Bye World from` with decreasing number after thread 10?

Comment: Sorry. My question should be more obvious. How does the execution order go from printing good bye world to printing thread 10 finished? Since the if statement is true, how do I get in the else and execute only the lines after the join method? Does The join method create a checkpoint for the program to go to as soon as the execution of the last start method finishes?

Comment: And where is the recursiveness in all this?

Comment: @JayC667 I am new to java and threads so I am studying code that i can find. This is not my code. Hence I do not know if it is entirely or at all correct.

Comment: Oh wait, now that I look at it, it actually IS recursive. Was wondering where you got that 'keyword' from, but you're actually right. Well, short answer to your question: Thread 1 starts Thread 2 (which starts Thread 3, which in turn starts Thread 4 etc.) BUT after Thread 1 started Thread 2 (and Thread x started Thread x+1), they all wait on the Thread they started, so the last Thread (limit) actually has to finish, then Thread limit-1 can continue and finish, then Thread limit-2 can continue and finish,and so on.Theres lots of multithreading but almost no parallel exec due to tight start/join

Comment: @JayC667 I got it now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start a new thread with `myId` 9 the code path you will follow in the `run` method is the `else` branch. In this branch you use `myId + 1` to spawn the final thread and wait for this final thread to join. On line 46 you will print the "Thread x finished" message in which you will also use `myId + 1`.

So basically, the `run` method of thread 9 will print that thread 10 finished and the `run` method of thread 10 does what you correctly assumed - take the `if` branch and only print "Goodbye".

Just to clarify:

- "Hello World" is printed after the thread has started at the
  beginning of its `run` method.
- "Good Bye" is printed when the `run` method approaches its end. The thread is still alive here, but will return after the printing is done.
- "Thread X finished" is printed **outside** of thread X since it ended already. Outside means in the outer thread (`myId - 1`) or in the main thread for thread 0.
- There is no "Thread 0 finished" message because in 0's outer thread (the main thread `main`) there is no such statement, but instead "Threads all done"